# InitialContext Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY lucene4 ejb3

Tags: lucene, factory, ejb-3.1, hibernate-4.x, initial-context

i'm use hibernate4 lucene4 in EJB3.

it ran perfectly but when i added a transaction in first managed bean.
the InitialContext return :
`javax naming not found in ctx.lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");`

> ex = (javax.naming.NamingException) javax.naming.NamingException:
>   Lookup failed for 'java:comp/UserTransaction' in 
>   SerialContext[myEnv=java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
>   java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
>   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root
>   exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Recherche de
>   java:comp/UserTransaction non autorisée pour les beans Transaction
>   gérés par le conteneur]

I think, the `context` implementation is different, and he need a props in `InitialContext`,

1. I called the ejb transaction from simple class from first managed bean,
2. I called InitialContext from another EJB3 from two managed bean

Comment: I find another solution ... i brok specification EJB for all first  invocation ... and it run

Comment: the problem form the java.naming invocation in glassfish ..